# Getting CSS selector for font tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to write css selector that will access font tag? I wrote a code in Python with BeautifulSoup lib that looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Lets say that my response looks like this:

```
<div class = "article">
  <div class = "news">
    <h1>headline 1</h1>
    <font>font text 2</font>
    <p>text 3</p>
    <p>text 4</p>
    <p>text 5</p>
    <p>text 6</p>
    <font>font text 7</font>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get only paragraphs so I did this:

```
news_links = soup.select("div.article div.news p") #returns list of p 
print(news_links)
```

But when I do this:

```
news_links = soup.select("div.article div.news font") 
print(news_links)
```

It returns empty list.
This method works with every html tag (div, span, table, li, ul, a etc.) except for font tag.

This is the exact website:

http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=909

I want to extract date: `Veröffentlicht am: 11:49:56 06.11.2020`, but when I place this as css selector

```
div#middle font font
```

returns empty list.

Comment: It should work with `font` as well. Make sure that `font` node present in HTML source file - it might be generated dynamically

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do; what's your expected output? `font text x`?

Comment: The Selector should be working. Please share the link to the website

Comment: @JackFleeting yes, I want to extract text that is in font tag.

Comment: @MendelG Every other selector is working good except from font

Comment: @taga please share the link

Comment: @MendelG I did, check out the question

Comment: I can see required text, but it's not in a `font` node. Are you sure you're trying to handle correct element?

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is the second text element under `id="middle"`, so use `find_next()` twice:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=909'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('#middle').find_next(text=True).find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
Veröffentlicht am: 11:49:56 06.11.2020
```